# mechanism to take code coverage using cppunit

Tags: c++, arm, code-coverage, keil, cppunit

- I need to take the code coverage of my product code.
- We use cppunit for unit testing. The complete code is in cpp.
- Compilation of code takes place using make files.
- Is there any way to take the code coverage using cppunit?
- We do not use linux.
- We use Keil for debugging and eclipse for code browsing.

Answer (score 0):

CppUnit is not a code coverage tool. But it isn't *incompatible* with code coverage tools. So the answer is, you'd measure code coverage as with any other application.  With Keil, you either need to be running in the simulator, or capture an instruction trace from your device using device-specific tools. Then you'd just load the trace into Keil's coverage analyzer.

Comment: Thanks Sneftel, but could you please be more specific with how can we take code coverage (steps to take code coverage) by running in the simulator from keil.